# Django using variables in Template Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

the website that I'm working on is using a model for a post, and another linked model for an image that would be attached to the post.

```
page_choices = {
    ('news', 'news'),
    ('activities', 'activities'),
    ('environment', 'environment'),
    ('affairs', 'affairs'),
    ('links', 'links'),
}
link_choices = {
    ('external', 'external'),
    ('none', 'none'),
    ('pdf', 'pdf'),
    ('image', 'image'),
}
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    page = models.CharField(
        choices=page_choices,
        max_length=11,
        default='news',
    )
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length = 100)
    content = models.CharField(null=True, max_length = 10000)
    image_filename = models.ForeignKey('Image', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    has_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length = 100)
    identifier = models.CharField(null=True, max_length = 100)
    alt_text = models.CharField(null=True, max_length = 100)
    link_address = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length = 100, help_text="Optional")
    link = models.CharField(
        choices=link_choices,
        max_length=8,
        default='none',
    )
```

These models are presented by the view to the HTML, and I'm trying to add JS/jQuery to add link functionality to the image. I'm trying to get a link to the static directory for an pdf that should be rendered when an image is clicked.

```
{% if post.image_filename.link == "pdf" %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#{{post.image_filename.identifier}}").click(function() {
            location.href = "{% static 'images/{{ post.image_filename.link_address }}' %}";
        });
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Putting {{  }} inside a template tag {%  %} doesn't work, and I've tried using `{% with post.image_filename.link_address as link_address %}` and I was unable to get that to work in this context either:

```
$("#{{post.image_filename.identifier}}").click(function() {
    location.href = "{% static 'images/post.image_filename.link_address' %}";
});
```

```
TemplateSyntaxError 'with' received an invalid token: 'post.image_filename.image_file'
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the [**`|add`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with post.image_filename.link_address as item %}
    location.href = "{% static 'images/'|add:item %}";
{% endwith %}
```